# length of circumference of a circle

Tags: integration, circles

Find the length of the circumference of a circle, whose equation is $r=2acos\theta$. I have tried differentiating with respect to $\theta$. I don't know what to do next. I seek a formula for solving this problem.

Comment: Why differentiate?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $r$ and change to Cartesian coordinates to get $$(x-a)^2+y^2=a^2$$ which is a circle.

The radius is $a$ so the circumference is $$2\pi a$$

Comment: Where did the ∅ go?

Comment: it went into $x$ because $r\cos \phi =x$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that by polar coordinates

- $r=x^2+y^2$
- $x=r\cos \phi$
- $y=r\sin \phi$